# How to find current location of the user using map_view in flutter?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, flutter

I would like to set initialCameraPosition to point to the user's current position rather than hard code a longitude and latitude.

```
  showMap() {
     mapView.show(
      new MapOptions(
          mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
          showUserLocation: true,
          initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(
              new Location(23.2599, 77.4126), 10.0),
          title: "Parking Spaces"),
      toolbarActions: [new ToolbarAction("Close", 1)]
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can hard code the position you want to show for default:

```
  MapView  mapView = new MapView();
  mapView.show(
      new MapOptions(
        title: 'map title',
        showUserLocation: true,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(new Location(35.7050274, 51.364935),11.92)
      )
    );
```

then bind a function to map view so when gps find user location camera position get updated:

```
mapView.onLocationUpdated.lastWhere((position)=>this.onUserLocationUpdated(position,mapView));
```

the method name `lastWhere` is called once on user location update if you want to track user movement you can use `listen`instead.
after that you just need to define a function that change camera position to user current position :

```
onUserLocationUpdated(position,MapView mapview)async {
  double zoomLevel = await mapview.zoomLevel;
  mapview.setCameraPosition(position.latitude, position.longitude, zoomLevel);
}
```

in above code we get user zoom level so every movement dont change current zoom level of user .